# 401 error reported by users. No error in server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on ASP.NET application. One of our servers suddenly started behaving differently than others. 
No issues until yesterday when suddenly users started reporting :
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

However, while browsing the website directly from server doesnt give any error.
Any ideas.

Comment: Are you using URL Rewriting or Response.Redirect... ? Probably one route or path changed permissions... Try go to IIS Authentication diagnostics http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e90fe777-4a21-4066-bd22-b931f7572e9a&DisplayLang=en

Comment: Authentication Control Diagnostics for IIS, has apparently changed in recent versions of IIS. But, that will give you a hint to know what kind of request is giving that error to your users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 401 error measn that the account used to access the files does not have enough privileges for the content requested.  There are a number of areas to check:

1)  What is the user account that the application pool is running under?
2)  What authentication scheme is the website running under?
3)  Do the accounts that the application pool and any impersonated accounts at the website level have the correct permissions at the file / folder level.

Typically, application pools are set up, in IIS 7, to run under the IIS_IUSRS account.  This account needs at least read access to the folder the website is set up on.  If you are using anonymous authentication on your site, that should fix you up.  If you are using windows / basic authentication, you'll need to make sure the user who is authenticating has rights to the folder.

The reason you can see the site, most likely, on the server is because the account you are accessing the website with already has rights to the server.  You now need to try from outside the server to get a real world comparison of what other user accounts have access to.

You also mention the word servers.  Make sure you aren't running into a double-hop scenario of using windows authentication and then trying to access a resource on another server with those credentials (impersonation).  This is only possible in a kerberos environment.

Comment: No, it doesn't. 401 means they are not authenticated at all. Your description sounds like a 403.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html - The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those credentials.

Comment: That is what I was referring to: "The request requires user authentication." It's not talking about privileges.